# Is there an AWS AMI for node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there are maintained AWS EC2 AMI made for node.js?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install on the standard Amazon Linux AMI. For development and low traffic the micro-instance is great/low cost.

If you want a ready-to-go install check out No.de - sign up and generate a coupon. Free for now as well.

Answer (score 15):

There isn't a specific pre-canned AMI, but you can install node.js in an instance based on a suitable AMI and then shrink-wrap your new build into an AMI of your own.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the free images built and maintained by StrongLoop. There are images for stable versions of node, for every region. You can search for "StrongLoop" under images. Latest version of node on these images is 0.10.26.

```
USWest Oregon       -  ami-14d5bf24,     
USEast              - ami-6541590c,        
USWest N California - ami-5a3e061f,  
Ireland             - ami-f154ae86,  
AP Singapore        - ami-5a7f2c08,  
AP Tokyo            - ami-3d2a513c,  
AP Sidney           - ami-b5178f8f,  
AP Sao Paulo        - ami-1919bb04,
```

Along with node, these images also have StrongLoop cli tools which can be used to simplify the deployment of node apps to AWS EC2.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami provide a free Node.js Amazon AMI ready to deploy in Amazon regions. You can see the full details here:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B008ASK0ZE/ref=mkt_blg_jb_wir617

Comment: This version has been removed and is no longer available to new customers.

Answer (score 1):

As lot of link in the answer is broken or the AMI does not update with the latest version. Bitname offer **maintained public AMI in all region** from node version `6.x to 12.x` and here is the [link](https://bitnami.com/stack/nodejs/cloud/aws/amis).

**AMAZON WEB SERVICES PUBLIC AMIS FOR BITNAMI NODE.JS STACK**

> The following tables include information about the Amazon Machine
>   Images (AMIs) available for Bitnami Node.js Stack in us west.

**US West (Oregon)**

```
Operating system    Node.js version AMI
Debian 9 (64-bit)   12.14.1-0   ami-0e574ff761aeba6b7
Debian 9 (64-bit)   10.18.1-0   ami-009fda657547a35a9
Debian 9 (64-bit)   8.17.0-0    ami-056ed886007a4c62f
Debian 9 (64-bit)   6.17.1-2    ami-027a0f9721892fc45
```

You can find all related and update to AMI https://bitnami.com/stack/nodejs/cloud/aws/amis.

*The user will be bitnami*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are likely community supported AMIs that include Nodejs, however you'll probably get better mileage using a tool like [OpDemand](http://www.opdemand.com/).  They offer a number of [different Node.js stacks](https://app.opdemand.com/templates/system/core) that you can deploy on AWS for free.  If you pair OpDemand's free account with a t1.micro, you can host and manage the whole thing for free!

Comment: links are not valid anymore.